# Curl on windows using Http/2 and windows authentication ( SPNEGO, Kerberos, Negotiate)

Tags: windows, authentication, curl, kerberos, http2

i have been trying to get curl version 7.63 on windows to connect to an HTTP/2 REST api and use Windows Authentication.

the REST Endpoint is setup to do "negotiate" and is running on a "Domain Joined" windows server. so it will get kerberos delegation from the Windows DC KDC.

This all works in http/1.1 but if i try do force curl to use http/2 it will revert to http/1.1

when i use "basic" authentication, than curl can connect to the rest endpoint using http/2.

i found this blog post from a former IIS engineer at microsoft, which says that IIs does not support Http/2 with Windows authentication.
https://blogs.iis.net/davidso/http2

since my REST Endpoint is responding with this in the header :
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

i believe it is using the same library as IIS and that could be the reason why it can't handle Windows Authentication ( Windows Authentication is needed to handle SSO so that the user does not need to enter his credentials).

is this a limitation in the http/2 specification or just a limitation in the microsoft libraries and IIS ?

curl 7.63.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) libcurl/7.63.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1a (WinSSL) zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.0.5 nghttp2/1.35.1
Release-Date: 2018-12-12
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile SSPI Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy MultiSSL Metalink

Answer (score 2):

[HTTP/2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/http2-on-iis)

In a few cases, HTTP/2 can't be used in combination with other features. In these situations, Windows will fall back to HTTP/1.1 and continue the transaction. This may involve negotiating HTTP/1.1 during the handshake, or sending an error code to the client instructing it to retry over an HTTP/1.1 connection.

Windows authentication (NTLM/Kerberos/Negotiate) is not supported with HTTP/2. In this case IIS will fall back to HTTP/1.1.
Clear text - as mentioned above, IIS currently only supports HTTP/2 over TLS. Again, IIS will fall back to HTTP/1.1.
Bandwidth throttling - IIS has a feature to limit bandwidth (in Inetmgr, select the site, 'Limits' under Configure of the Action pane). This applies to HTTP/1.1 but is not enforced for HTTP/2 (will proceed with no errors or bandwidth limiting).